# coordinate code address on google map?

Tags: google-maps, location

When I use "center: new google.maps.LatLng" this command, normally we use this format `(22.621177,120.298311)`.

But my source is `7 05.16' N, 171 21.88' E`

Does somebody know what to do next?

```
function load(User_Id) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.601914,120.283186),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


  downloadUrl("db_2_xml.php?id="+User_Id, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("markers");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var vessel = markers[i].getAttribute("vessel");


      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(
        geocoder.geocode(markers[i].getAttribute("GPS")));

  var speed = markers[i].getAttribute("speed");


      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: geocoder,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please expand on exactly what the problem is? Based on your question it appears you need to translate the location from one format to another. I'm sure there are libraries for this somewhere.

Comment: Normally we use "22.621177,120.298311" this format for google map.
But now, my system provide me "7 05.16' N, 171 21.88' E" this format.
I have try to force php use that format but not working.

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This sounds like you need to convert global position coordinates from DMS format `7 05.16' N, 171 21.8' E` to decimal format like `22.621177, 120.298311`. In your sample `88` seconds is more then the allowed 60 for that position.

This function will do the difficult part of converting from DMS to Decimal format. It does not validate  the values are in an acceptable range, nor does it carry the extra to the next greater unit position.

## Example

Live Example: http://ideone.com/h2xwAc

**Code**

```
<?php

function DMS2Decimal($degrees = 0, $minutes = 0, $seconds = 0, $direction = 'n') {
     //converts DMS coordinates to decimal
     //returns false on bad inputs, decimal on success

     //direction must be n, s, e or w, case-insensitive
     $d = strtolower($direction);
     $ok = array('n', 's', 'e', 'w');

     //degrees must be integer between 0 and 180
     if(!is_numeric($degrees) || $degrees < 0 || $degrees > 180) {
          $decimal = false;
     }
     //minutes must be integer or float between 0 and 59
     elseif(!is_numeric($minutes) || $minutes < 0 || $minutes > 59) {
          $decimal = false;
     }
     //seconds must be integer or float between 0 and 59
     elseif(!is_numeric($seconds) || $seconds < 0 || $seconds > 59) {
          $decimal = false;
     }
     elseif(!in_array($d, $ok)) {
          $decimal = false;
     }
     else {
          //inputs clean, calculate
          $decimal = $degrees + ($minutes / 60) + ($seconds / 3600);

          //reverse for south or west coordinates; north is assumed
          if($d == 's' || $d == 'w') {
               $decimal *= -1;
          }
     }

     return $decimal;
}



echo "x: " . DMS2Decimal($degrees = 7, $minutes = 5, $seconds = 16, $direction = 'n');

echo "y: " . DMS2Decimal($degrees = 171, $minutes = 21, $seconds = 8, $direction = 'e');
```

**Output**

```
x: 7.0877777777778y: 171.35222222222
```

## Inserting Into Your Code

Note this portion of the answer is untested and probably in the wrong spot. This is only to show an overview of how I would approach the problem. Note again there is no validation testing on any of the values.

```
function load(User_Id, x, y) {

// if the x coordinate is not a number then assume it is in DMS format and convert
    if (!is_numeric(x)) {
        x = DMS2Decimal(x)
    }

// if the y coordinate is not a number then assume it is in DMS format and convert
    if (!is_numeric(y)) {
        y = DMS2Decimal(y)
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
```

Comment: So, This will be another program.
I don't know how to fetch from mysql and calculate, than put back to mysql.

Comment: Your problem here is suffering from some serious scope creep. Pulling a value from MySql running a calculation and putting it back into MySql is really a completely different problem and should be presented as a completely new Stack Overflow question. I updated my answer to show how a x,y value could be tested and converted if necessary.